# Python saving results to .xls file giving error

Tags: python, excel, save

I am working on a project where I have to save the results to an excel file. I am giving the command at the end of the project, which has been working fine, but now giving me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\5460\Desktop\Code\scikit-learn svm_body.py", line 139, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\5460\Desktop\Code\scikit-learn svm_body.py", line 136, in main
    wb.save('SVMResults_body001.xls')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Workbook.py", line 662, in save
    doc.save(filename, self.get_biff_data())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Workbook.py", line 637, in get_biff_data
    shared_str_table   = self.__sst_rec()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Workbook.py", line 599, in __sst_rec
    return self.__sst.get_biff_record()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt\BIFFRecords.py", line 76, in get_biff_record
    self._add_to_sst(s)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt\BIFFRecords.py", line 91, in _add_to_sst
    u_str = upack2(s, self.encoding)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt\UnicodeUtils.py", line 55, in upack2
    raise Exception('String longer than 32767 characters')
Exception: String longer than 32767 characters
```

My part of the code is as below:

```
def main():
    classifier = svm_learning(data_array, cat_array) #for training classifier
    classified = list(classifier.predict(test_array))
    print classified
    pred_array = np.array(classified)
    #write to file
    z = 1
    for c in classified:
        worksheet.write(z,1,c)#1 is for body
        z += 1
    scores = classifier.score(test_array, cat_test_array) #test_array,cat_test_array
    print scores
    crossval = cross_validation.cross_val_score(classifier,test_array,cat_test_array, cv=5) #5 folds -- cv=5
    print crossval
    print("Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)" % (crossval.mean(), crossval.std() * 2))
    print 'It is saving now'
    wb.save('SVMResults_body001.xls')
```

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi. Thanks! yes I understood what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you are writing is longer than is allowed by the interface - more than 32k (the maximum value of a signed short integer). You need to cut the strings into shorter pieces.

Comment: If this happens during saving, how do I cut the string into pieces? Do you mean, split into different columns? How do I know which column/row gives this error?

Answer (score 1):

The total number of characters that a cell can contain is 32,767 (reference [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)).

Use this to add characters of more than 32k

```
Workbook wb = new Workbook(FileFormatType.CSV,CheckExcelRestriction='false')
```

and save as `.csv` instead of `.xls`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please remember to format your code.